# Angular 2 ADFS adal parameter removed because of hash location strategy

Tags: angular, adfs, angular-routing, adal

I have an angular 2 application and I´m using the adal lib to authenticate against adfs. This is actually working out of the box with the location strategy without hash, which is great. The ADFS redirect is sending this parameter, and adal-service is able to use it.

```
#id_token=<sometokenvalue>
```

But for some reasons I need to use the hash location strategy. In this case, the correct url pops up for a second in the browser´s address bar and then the angular router is doing some magic and my token is lost and the url looks like that:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/id_token
```

My SecretService looks like that:

```
 public get adalConfig(): any {
    return {
     tenant: 'adfs',
     instance: LoginConfig.getInstance(),
     clientId: LoginConfig.getClientId(),
     redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
     postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
     isAngular: true
   };
 }
```

The component which handles the redirect looks like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
    if (this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
      this.router.navigate(['/next']);
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to solve my problem...

To prevent angular to forward to another route before handling the token, I wrote a canActivateGuard, which is calling the handleWindowCallback() method first.

```
@Injectable()
export class HandleTokenCanActivateGuard implements CanActivate{

constructor(private adalService: AdalService) {}

canActivate() {
    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
    return true;
  }
}
```